# printing br tag and other tag dilema

Tags: javascript, html

this is the data from the db, and `i want to print as same as the data like this`

```
first line
second line
function ajax(){
return a;
}
<html></body>
<iframe src = "google.com">
test = "test"
```

after one line, it has new line(`\n`) in every line

so if i want to print this,

i have to change every new line to `<br/>`

but the problem is

```
<html></body>
<iframe src = "google.com">
```

this kind of tag element input. the requirement isto print these as `PURE STRING`

but if i print this as a pure string,

it will show

```
first line<br/>second line<br/>function ajax(){<br/>return a;<br/>}<br/><html></body>br/><iframe src = "google.com"><br/>test = "test"<br/>
```

like this,

if i put this with tags,

it will be

```
first line
second line
function ajax(){
return a;
}
//I HAVE TO PRINT TAG AS PURE STRING but javascript regcognize as tags
```

Any good idea for this???

Comment: could you show how you want it to be printed?

Comment: @Xyzk i want to print it like the first one which is in the db

Comment: downvoter could you explain your reasons? if this answer is not useful, it means that i didnt understand the question, but i think i did. otherwise i need some clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

have a look at the stackoverflow page,

```
<pre><code> ... </code></pre>
```

:)

cheers.